# Which user does vi run commands as?

Tags: permissions, users, vi

This maybe a weird question but please listen carefully

Let's say I have a file as

```
-rwxr-w--- user3 user2 4095  somefile
```

Right now I'm in a `user2`'s shell(? is this right to say) 
and if I execute this 'somefile' with vi editor, I guess this somefile belongs to the `user3`, So If I execute some command line in the vim, am I executing command in `user3`'s shell?

Comment: Do you mean the file mode is `-rwxrw----` or `-rwxr-x---`?

Comment: Please be specific about what you mean with "in `user2`'s shell".  Have you logged in as `user2`, or have you just used `cd` to change the directory to `user2`'s home directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `vim` is not set user id (that is, it will not change effective userid). running a command line from vim will give you a shell (that is the word) as `user2`.

By the way, to edit the file you must either

- be user `user3`
- belong to **group** `user2`, merely being user2 is not enough.

There used to be a bug in redhat  4.x (or still is) when running visudo, which allow you to run a shell as root. This was a light bug, as you must allready be in sudoers to run visudo.

Answer (score 3):

By saying you're in `user2`'s shell you imply you've been logged in as `user2`, the command `whoami` or `echo $LOGNAME` will let you know the same.

Whatever commands you are firing in the terminal are considered to be fired by the logged-in user, except for those through `sudo`.

The coloumn names in an output of `ls` is as below, for you reference. The **Fourth field** is to denote the `Group`.

```
PERMS       LINKS  OWNER     GROUP     SIZE     modMONTH  modDATE  modTIME  NAME
-rwx------  1      lg262728  lg262728  43457    Sep       20       2006     "cpufreq.c"
```